# Pain after overhead press

Tags: pain, press

I've been going to the gym for about a year. The last 3 months I decided to make my training routine a bit more, upper- back/ traps/ shoulder intensive. I basically am doing full body 3 times a week. On every training day after worm up I started with overhead pressing. The problem is that about 2 weeks ago i got injured. Started feeling pain from my neck area going trough my left shoulder. When I run my fingers trough my upper part of my spine I am feeling pain. My question is firstly is this due to bad form in your opinion or just the overloading I've been doing to my upper back. Second should I try and wait out the pain to disappear on its own or should I go see a doctor?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Go see a doctor.

Comment: This will probably get closed since we're not doctors (well, most of us aren't). Having said that, I'd go for a decent sports massage and make sure you're doing enough upper back pulling work.

Comment: @DarkHippo - Recommending a course of treatment without any visual or other clues aside from "Wow my neck hurts" is fairly dangerous. Hope the sports massage doesn't exacerbate an actual injury.

Comment: @JohnP A good sports masseur would be able to diagnose the issue and know what to do to avoid exacerbating it. In my experience a doctor will only tell you to rest if the injury is anything muscular.

Answer (score 2):

I would take it easy, or do different exercises, until the pain goes away. If it persists, then I would go see the doctor. The impact from running can aggravate neck injuries. Stick to lower body exercises and no impact exercises for a week and see how you feel. If you are ready to re-introduce upper body strength exercises then, start with exercises where your hands stay below the shoulders (seated row, push ups... nothing overhead)